# How to turn off command feedback in command prompt

Tags: cmd, converters, love2d

I am creating a LOVE compiler with batch and it uses copy commands to copy

It works, but every time it copies a file it says `1 file(s) copied.`
is there any way to turn this off?

command > NUL is working for everything but the actual compiling code
`copy /B /Y Convert.exe+*.love Build\"%answer%.exe`, where it says `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. 0 file(s) copied.`, for some reason,> NUL breaks it, any way to fix it?

Edit: lonely quote in code here, that's the reason its breaking

Comment: In yout cmd script add `>NUL` after the copy command

Comment: The following syntax should redirect all output to the NUL device, _(which means that it will not show in your output)_: `@(COPY [/D] [/V] [/N] [/Y | /-Y] [/Z] [/L] [/A | /B ] "source" [/A | /B] [+ "source" [/A | /B] [+ …]] ["destination" [/A | /B]]) 1> NUL 2>&1`

Comment: Compo gave you the answer more than an hour ago. What's wrong with it?

Comment: What's that lonely quote in your code? And how does it "break it"? And there is no compiler in `cmd`.

Comment: I am making one with cmd. no, I didn't notice that but for some reason, it didn't matter when >NUL wasn't added thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just redirect standard output to the NUL device:

```
copy %SRC% %DEST% > NUL
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to say.  The point is, you take your _working_ `copy` command and you add `> NUL` to the end of it.  Your question did not specify any required behavior for error conditions -- you have only asked how to "hide" the message that is displayed after successful copying.  Your description, "this is a love compiler", does not add any kind of useful clarification.  What you are building is irrelevant.